# How to use GraphQLProvider inside MultiProvider?

Tags: flutter, graphql, state-management, flutter-provider

```
 MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthProvider(authService: AuthService()),
        ),
        GraphQLProvider(...),
      ],
)
```

The element type `GraphQLProvider` can't be assigned to the list type `SingleChildWidget`.